# Can you start your turn when you're dead?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-death

In my epic game, I am playing a level 30 Keeper of the everflow.

Keepers have a level 24 feature:

> Life Overflow (24th level): Once per day when you start your turn at 0 hit points or fewer, you regain hit points equal to your bloodied value and end all effects of your choice that are affecting you.

If an attack brings you to negative bloodied, is your turn order preserved in the initiative order?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no." But... death has always been... funky... in D&D. And this is a funky edge case of I hate their wording so much.

Comment: I'm guessing no, otherwise it would include _Once per day when you die..._

Comment: It's important to note the distinction between "dead" and "dying". This power is meant to allow you to recover from "dying" not from "dead".

Answer (score 14):

**You have no turns if you are dead** (or more accurately if you are destroyed)

Form the Rules Compendium p197

> **THE STRUCTURE OF A TURN**
>
> When a creature's turn comes up in the initiative order, it can do things. A creature's
>   turn has three parts: the start of the turn; the actions of the turn, if any;
>   and the end of the turn. Of course, if a creature is destroyed, it has no turns!

Destroy is typically used for objects and for summoned or conjured things, but on p313, we have:

> minion [role]: A minion is destroyed when it takes any damage.

So it would appear that a creature "dead" is also a creature "destroyed"

As for is your initiative preserved? That appears to be a trickier thing, though I'm not sure that it actually matters for the analysis of this question.

Comment: but are PCs creatures?  I don't know the system well enough to know, but I suspect there may be a difference...

Comment: @Ryno - yes, creatures are most certainly creatures.

Comment: @Ryno - or more usefully, yes, player characters are most certainly creatures.

Comment: Once you hit negative your bloodied value, you are dead. Not dying. You can't do anything while dead, and that includes this power.

Comment: @DampeS8N, while both I, and my answer agree with you, what I think Brian is looking for is a rules citation.

Comment: @SimonWithers I had trouble understanding what this question was about and the comment above was intended to help people like me 'click' onto what this is all about. Consider it a clue.